# Servlet thread pool

Tags: servlets, threadpool

When threads are re-used from a thread-pool by a servlet, what happens to all the references they hold once they are returned to the pool? Are they somehow set to null? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The thread doesn't hold any reference, other than those set by the servlet container itself, and those potentially stored in a ThreadLocal variable by your own code.

And those are not set to null.